# Form: Show entry after a click below a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to see the entry appear below the form after clicking on the button. Unfortunately, my creation does not work.

[this is what the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3DZj.jpg)

Here my not working script jQuery + form/html (I would like to implement it with jquery):

**JS:**

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#name").on("keyup", function() { 
        var value = $(this).val(); 
        $("p.giveout").text(value); 
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="form">
    <label for="name">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
    <p class="giveout">Hallo <strong>Anon!</strong></p>
    <script src="lib/js/my.js"></script>
</section>
```

What am I doing wrong?
I wrote two scripts. How do I bring it together?

THE FIRST ONE

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
    $("p.giveout").html("Neuer Text");
});
```

THE SECOND SCRIPT

```
$(function() { 
    $("#name").on("keyup", function() { 
        var value = $(this).val(); 
        $("p.giveout").text(value); 
    });
});
```

Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Hi Fl1tz,

I think this can solve your problem:

```javascript
$( function() { 
   $( "#name" ) 
        .on ("change", function() { 
      $( "p.giveout" ).text( $(this).val() ); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it.

Comment: @ N'Bayramberdiyev -> Thank you very much! That worked! I changed it in that way: $( function() { $( "#name" ) .on ("change", function() { $( "p.giveout" ).text( "Hallo " + $(this).val() ); }); }); I want to make the variable bold. Citing STRONG before and after the variable does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty this approch, might help you:

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#name').val();
    $("p.giveout strong").html(text);
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="form">
    <label for="name">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="button" id="submit">
    <p class="giveout">Hallo <strong>Anon!</strong></p>
    <script src="lib/js/my.js"></script>
</section>
```

Comment: -> Wonderful !!! - In this version, however, I must definitely write the reference to the js file under the form. Or?